# Ok for Raspberry Pi to cause retract cycles (HDD)

Tags: external-hard-drive, raspberry-pi, disk-operating-system

I was wondering if it is ok if the Raspberry Pi 3B+ causes my HDD to have a power off retract everytime the OS i use is shutdown/rebooted? Can this affect my HDD lifetime? Im using 1TB seagate expansion drive 2018. Whenever the Pi shutsdown/restarts i hear a small noise coming from the disk, i think its because of the "Power off/emergency retract cycle". I got the data from S.M.A.R.T. I currently have 18, i got the HDD yesterday.

Comment: "Can this affect my HDD lifetime?" -- absolutely.  It can give it one.  That's there to protect the drive from accidental damage.  But it is actually handled by the drive, itself, rather than the Raspberry Pi.  Nothing to worry about; it won't wear anything out.  It does that by design.

Comment: This is a relief, I was wondering if the Pi could potentially destroy my drive this way. Could you post this as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this affect my HDD lifetime?

Absolutely. It can give it one. Head parking is there to protect the drive from accidental damage. But it is actually handled by the drive, itself, rather than the Raspberry Pi. Nothing to worry about; it won't wear anything out. It does that by design.